# 302 Redirect RequestError -- Moved Temporarily - while deleting an google calendar event

Tags: python, google-calendar-api, gdata, gdata-api

I try to delete an event in google calendar through my python code. Sometimes i succeed deleting but sometimes i get the below error. The problem is that it's not 100% reproducible

**My Error**

```
{'status': 302, 
'body': '<HTML>\n<HEAD>\n<TITLE>Moved Temporarily</TITLE>\n</HEAD>\n<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">\n<H1>Moved Temporarily</H1>\nThe document has moved <A HREF="http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/private/full/ii6k0j6big9iv9nbv3t5aqe88g/63518059677?gsessionid=rJs6gQ4fZ9gh3maHbhYRIg">here</A>.\n</BODY>\n</HTML>\n', 
'reason': 'Redirect received, but redirects_remaining <= 0'}
```

My Code (just the same as [api code](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v1/developers_guide_python#DeletingEvents))

```
def DeleteEvent(calendar_service, event):
  calendar_service.DeleteEvent(event.GetEditLink().href)
```

When i surfed i got to know that it's a [reported issue](http://code.google.com/p/googlecl/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Stars%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=167). But i am unable to identify the status of the bug. And if the bug is fixed is there a patch or updated gdata module available. I am completely struck on how to proceed. Kindly suggest some way to fix this issue. Thanks a lot for your time and energy. :)